# Hard drive dock w/usb and esata connectivity

Tags: dock, esata, card-reader

If I buy a SATA hard drive dock that also has a card reader, and 2 extra USB ports on the front, and I connect my MacPro to it via the new SATA PCIe Sata card I installed, will the ESATA connection wire also bridge to the USB ports and card reader slots, or will I have to unplug the esata wire, and plug in the mini USB port for card reader and extra USB port connecivity?
I have found NO WHERE this question is asked or answered!!

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing any other information, I would assume that the USB hub and card reader would only be functional when connected via USB, since eSATA definitely cannot carry that kind of data. It would be bad if the same drive were connected to your computer with USB and eSATA at the same time, so the best-case scenario for you in this situation would be if the dock intelligently disables the USB hard drive access when it sees an active eSATA connection. Can you help us by posting the make and model of the drive dock?

Comment: I agree with NReilingh here.  You would need to connect the USB cable for any card reader or USB port functionality. If you post the model number of the device, someone should be able to find solid information for you.